# Images Crashing Blender

Tags: image, osx

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro running on High Sierra but any time I try to open an image file on any part of Blender it crashes. I can't open an image texture, background image, etc. I've tried different images but they all give me the rainbow wheel of death. I'm guessing this is an issue with storage/hardware but I have no clue at this point. Any help would be great.

Comment: What happens when you render and the UV/Image editor displays that image?

Comment: Can you try an older version of Blender to see if there was a bug?

Comment: @3pointedit it causes my mac to give me the rainbow wheel of death. It shouldn't be a bug with the version because before I've been able to put images in just fine. It's only recently it's stopped working.

Comment: Did you download a new version of blender recently or do a Mac update? To narrow down the issue you would have to check that an older version still works. If it does not then its a change to the mac system, but thats still potentially a bug in Blender.

Comment: Found this mention in the bug tracker https://developer.blender.org/T52640 is this related?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Blender I was using was old. I updated to version 2.79b and that appears to have fixed the issue.